# Why is my lex output .exe not returning any responds? (Failing at hello world)

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am trying to understand lex/yacc and currently I am failing at hello world. I probably messed something up, somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Also, I am not experienced with C language or with lex/flex/yacc/bison so this is all new to me.

test.l file;

```
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}

%%

"hey"       printf("hello!");

%%

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile this on windows, with the commands;

```
lex test.l
```

This returns lex.yy.c file without errors or warnings.
I then compile with;

```
cc lex.yy.c
```

Which without errors or warnings, creates the a.exe as supposed too.
When i then run the file with input from another file;

```
a.exe < input
```

It returns nothing.

Input file;

```
"hey"
```

Any information is welcome, since every single guide I found either creates errors (when literally copy pasted, even after clean install and guided-install) or is simply outdated or listed for "windows" while it uses commands that are non-windows >.<

Comment: Your `main` does nothing except return - how are you expecting it to call the lexer code?

Comment: The first rule would be to *carefully compare your code with the examples*, even before posting to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It's the double quotes in the `"hey"` in your *.l* file they actually don't mean `"hey"` they mean `hey` so if you change your input file to just say *hey* rather than *"hey"* your code should work. If you want to parse `"` then your rule should be: `"\"hey\""`

Also `lex` should auto include `stdio.h` so you probably don't need it.

LOL you forgot to call yylex();

So:

```
%option noyywrap
%%

"hey"       printf("hello!");

%%

int main()
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

### Important subtlety

You will see this behaviour occur and you may not notice it right away but

Your *original* code will give you and output. The match *will* occur even with *\"hey\"* output and you will get:

> "hello!"

Notice the `"`'s.

That's because lex injects a *default* rule for any character matching to just spit it back out, and because your `"hey"` rule matches `hey` and you have `"`'s around the input the quotes come out in the `"hello!"`

Comment: First off, thank you for your reply :)     Removed the quotations from "hey" and still gives nothing back.
Removed the stdio.h and tried again, still nothing.

Comment: I missed the lack of call to `yylex()` too ... it happens

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` does nothing - you need to call the lexer.

```
int main()
{
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am slightly ashamed right now... But yeah, this fixed it :P